# Converting Set of ARC/INFO ASCII .e00, .e01, .e02, etc files into shapefiles using QGIS

Tags: shapefile, qgis, ogr

I have a set of files that I downloaded with extensions (.e00, .e01, .e02, etc).  I have read that these are files used by ARC Info mainly, but I do not have ARC and nor am I really that interested in downloading it.  The funnier thing is that I am able to convert a .e00 file in QGIS to a .shp set, but if the file has been broken into many .e0n files, QGIS does not recognize the others and leaves me with only have my shapefile.  I have tried taking the other files and copying and pasting their contents to the end of the .e00 file, but this resulted in a very erroneous shape in QGIS.  I have been searching for some while now if there is a way to do this with ogr2ogr, but haven't found anything for a set of files like this.  I also downloaded e002shp, but had no idea on how to go about using it and didn't find much online for that one.

Can you tell me any command-line tools I could use (preferably ogr2ogr) or a way to do this in QGIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the batch importer by esri import71.exe

[e002arc](http://gis.esri.com/download/download.cfm?file=import71.exe)

Then I guess you would need to convert the arc to shp since you don't have esri with...

[arc3shp](http://www.mediafire.com/?njtuyjmyzyn)

Sorry I have not tried the second software. I have autodesk map and arcgis as well as FME and they all convert arcinfo to shape. If this is a one time problem you might find someone (like me) willing to help.

Answer (score 3):

if you are on windows you can read all about it here
http://freegeographytools.com/2007/converting-e00-vector-data-to-shapefiles-a-free-and-fairly-painless-approach

Answer (score 0):

```
ogr2ogr t5190.shp t5190.e00
```

Should do the trick.

Sometimes you could try combining the files prior to running ogr2ogr.

```
cat filename.e0* >filename-merged.e00
```

Other possibilities: there is a module in saga gis ([Import ESRI E00 File](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_modules_doc/io_esri_e00/index.html)) that can do the trick. From that link it seems that also grass has a function to import these files.